# SVG Object displaying SVG Code instead of SVG Graphic?

Tags: object, svg

on my website I have an SVG Object which is meant to display a vector image, whilst testing this offline, everything worked fine, but when I uploaded it onto my website, the object displays the code of the SVG in question. viewable here: [link to site with svg](http://www.pinpointbadges.com/lanyarddesigner.php)

Object Code:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="ppvisual.svg" width="702px" height="259.37px">
<param name="colour" value="<?php echo $colour; ?>" />
<param name="textcolour" value="<?php echo $textcolour; ?>" />
<param name="lanyardtext" value="<?php echo $lanyardtext; ?>" />
</object>
```

Doctype: (incase that has anything to do with it?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

SVG code:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="702px" height="259.37px" viewBox="0 0 702 259.37" enable-background="new 0 0 702 259.37" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<g>
    <polygon fill="none" points="0,80.811 0.053,113.105 48.17,112.998 48.117,80.705         "/>

        <image overflow="visible" width="109" height="188" xlink:href="fitment1.png"  transform="matrix(4.854395e-04 0.2963 -0.2559 5.628683e-04 48.1172 80.7046)">
    </image>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="param(colour) white" d="M43.807,108.613c-0.241,0-0.476-0.086-0.659-0.248
    c-0.217-0.189-0.341-0.463-0.341-0.752v-22.26c0-0.502,0.372-0.926,0.87-0.991l633.935-83.34c0.043-0.005,0.086-0.008,0.129-0.008
    c0.264,0,0.52,0.104,0.707,0.293l22.26,22.26c0.188,0.188,0.293,0.442,0.293,0.707v61.08c0,0.553-0.447,1-1,1h-22.26
    c-0.553,0-1-0.447-1-1v-59.94L43.938,108.605C43.894,108.611,43.851,108.613,43.807,108.613z"/>
<path fill="#636466" d="M677.74,2.013L700,24.273v61.08h-22.26v-61.08l-633.933,83.34v-22.26L677.74,2.013 M677.74,0.013
    c-0.086,0-0.174,0.005-0.26,0.017L43.546,83.371c-0.995,0.13-1.739,0.979-1.739,1.982v22.26c0,0.576,0.248,1.125,0.681,1.504
    c0.367,0.322,0.836,0.496,1.319,0.496c0.086,0,0.174-0.006,0.261-0.016L675.74,26.553v58.8c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2H700
    c1.105,0,2-0.896,2-2v-61.08c0-0.53-0.211-1.039-0.586-1.414l-22.26-22.26C678.777,0.222,678.268,0.013,677.74,0.013L677.74,0.013z
    "/>
</g>
<g>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="param(colour) white" d="M43.807,108.613c-0.552,0-1-0.447-1-1v-22.26c0-0.552,0.448-1,1-1
    H700c0.404,0,0.77,0.244,0.924,0.617c0.155,0.374,0.069,0.804-0.217,1.09l-22.26,22.26c-0.188,0.188-0.441,0.293-0.707,0.293
    H43.807z"/>
<path fill="#636466" d="M700,85.353l-22.26,22.26H43.807v-22.26H677.74H700 M700,83.353h-22.26H43.807c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2v22.26
    c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2H677.74c0.53,0,1.039-0.211,1.414-0.586l22.26-22.26c0.572-0.572,0.743-1.432,0.434-2.18
    C701.538,83.84,700.809,83.353,700,83.353L700,83.353z"/>
</g>
<rect x="0" y="186.505" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="param(colour) white" width="702" height="70.865"/>
<path fill="#636466" d="M702,257.37H0v2h702V257.37z M702,186.505v-2l0,0H0v2H702"/>
<g>
<defs>
    <polygon id="SVGID_1_" points="677.74,107.613 43.807,107.613 43.807,85.353 677.74,85.353 700,85.353         "/>
</defs>
<clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
</clipPath>
<g clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 372 102.272)" fill="param(textcolour) white" font-family="'Verdana-Bold'" font-size="16" text-anchor="middle" content-value="param(lanyardtext)">Enter Your Text          Enter Your Text          Enter Your Text          Enter Your Text</text>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<defs>
    <rect id="SVGID_3_" x="0" y="186.505" width="702" height="70.865"/>
</defs>
<clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  overflow="visible"/>
</clipPath>
<g clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)">
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 350 240.0977)" fill="param(textcolour) white" font-family="'Verdana-Bold'" font-size="50.9319" text-anchor="middle" content-value="param(lanyardtext) white">Enter Your Text          Enter Your Text          Enter Your Text          Enter Your Text</text>
</g>
</g>

<script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="param.js" />
</svg>
```

I'm thinking this might be something about server setting? anybody have any idea how I would fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the SVG data with a mime type of text/plain. You need to reconfigure your web server to send it with a mime type of image/svg+xml. How you do that depends on what web server you are using.